# Angular app test with Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine tests with Karma. I'm getting following error while executing the tests.

[image]

Here are my files.

**message.service.js**  // Service file

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

    angular.module("app").factory('MessageService', [MessageService]);

    function MessageService() {
        var service = {};
        //var gui = require('nw.gui');

      service.alert = function() {
        //gui.Window.open('/');
            //$window.open('/message');
            return 'hello';
      };

      return service;
    };

})(); // IIFE
```

**message.service.spec.js** // Service test file

```
describe('Message Service', function() {

  var messageService;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_MessageService_) {
    messageService = _MessageService_;
  }));

  it('should exist', function() {
    expect(messageService).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should return hello', function() {
    expect(messageService.alert()).toEqual('hello');
  });

});
```

**app.module.js** // Main app file

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);

    /*angular.module("app").run(['$rootScope', 'StartupService', function($rootScope, startupService){
        startupService.init($rootScope);
    }]);*/

})(); // IIFE
```

If I change following line in message.service.js

```
angular.module("app").factory('MessageService', [MessageService]);
```

to

```
angular.module("app",[]).factory('MessageService', [MessageService]);
```

Then tests work fine but application will not work(due to re initiation of module I guess). How can I make my app to work for both tests and normal app execution? Appreciate your help

Comment: post your message.js file

Comment: hi aruna, tell me

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan,
It's the same file message.service.js. I just renamed.

Comment: But the error file is showing as message.js , did you rerun again?

Comment: Sorry, message.service.spec.js is the message.js file

Comment: I ran the test with message.js file but when I'm posting it here just mentioned it as message.service.spec.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131975/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-aruna).

Comment: Hey try to add all the dependencies including ui-router to the karma.config file, it should work

Comment: You would get must more readable error messages if you didn't use the minified version of angular during development.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I haven't included the js file in Karma config related to the ui.bootstrap module. After that it worked fine.

For anyone who gets such error check whether you have included all the dependency files on Karma config, what you have defined in main app.

ex: assume your main app file is like below.

```
angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);
```

Then your Karma config file should look like this

```
files: [
  'assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js',
  'assets/lib/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js',
  'assets/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.min.js'
],
```

Thanks for your help.